# Rewrite perl cgi-bin URL's with multiple parameters using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, seo, url-rewriting

I'm working on a PERL site which uses the medoc ecommerce system, and I've found that is spits out really ugly URL's which have no meaning to users or search engines:
https://www.example.com/cgi-bin/live/ecommerce.pl?site=test.com&dept_id=01&sub_dept_id=01&menu=currency&zone=test

I want to rewrite this so it's something simple like https://www.example.com/travel-money/home-delivery

Any ideas how I would go about this?

There are perhaps 50 different cgi-bin URL's each with multiple parameters, and I'd like to rewrite all of them individually.

I came up with two different rewrite rules, but neither worked. I couldn't find any examples with multiple parameters:

Option 1:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^site=test.com&dept_id=01&sub_dept_id=01&menu=currency&zone=test$
RewriteRule ^/cgi-bin/live/ecommerce.pl https://www.example.com/travel-money/home-delivery [L,R=301]
```

Option 2:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)test.com&dept_id=01&sub_dept_id=01&menu=currency&zone=ice$
RewriteRule ^cgi-bin/live/ecommerce.pl$ travel-money/home-delivery? [R=301,L]
```

Thanks,

Comment: Removed the perl tag, as the fact that it is a Perl site is not relevant to this particular question.

Comment: You're redirecting a URL with query strings too one that doesn't exist. If you go to `https://www.example.com/travel-money/home-delivery`, don't you get a 404 not found? If you redirect the browser to something that doesn't exist, it's not going to work.